# Алгоритмы, как изменятся сложность при увеличении данных?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Алгоритм работает за O(n) времени и O(n^2) памяти.
Если количество входящих данных увеличить в 2 раза то что получим?

В 2 раз увеличится время выполнения и в 4 раза память. Так ли?

время - линейно, в 2 раза увеличили кол-во данных в 2 раза дольше будет работать программа

Память - в 4 раза (цикл в цикле)

Мне сказали что я не прав, но я не могу понять почему((((

Comment: Слушайте, где это вас так терроризируют?... И кто? Вопрос стоял именно так — за время O(n) и память O(n^2) или вы **сами это вывели** (эти О)? Может, вы неверно их получили? Потому что цикл в цикле — это обычно время O(n^2)...

Comment: А, не, ничего не выводил, вопрос так звучит "Алгоритм работает за O(n) времени и O(n^2) памяти. Если количество входящих данных увеличить в 2 раза то во сколько увеличится асимптотика?"

Comment: *Асимптотика* не увеличивается. Какие-то у вас вопросы в духе "летят два крокодила, один на север, другой зеленый"...

Comment: Ну вообще можно в этом случае только сказать, что время увеличится линейно, а память квадратично, но что именно в 2 и в 4 раза гарантии, конечно, нет.